# Reading quickly from many random points of a file

Tags: file, rust

I am in the process of developing a performance-critical network service in Rust. A request to my service looks like a vector `ids: Vec<u64>` of numerical ids. For each `id` in `ids`, my service must read the `id`-th record from a long sequence of records stored contiguously on an SSD. Because all records have the same size `RECORD_SIZE` (in practice, around 6 KB), the position of every record is entirely predictable, so a trivial solution reduces to

```
for id in ids {
   file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(id * RECORD_SIZE)).unwrap();
   let mut record = vec![0u8; RECORD_SIZE];
   file.read_exact(&mut record).unwrap();

   records.push(record);
}

// Do something with `records`
```

Now, sadly, the following apply:

- The elements of `ids` are non-contiguous, unpredictable, unstructured, and effectively equivalent to distributed uniformly at random in the range `[0, N]`.
- `N` is way too large for me to store the entire file in memory.
- `ids.len()` is much smaller than `N`, so I cannot efficiently cycle through the file linearly without having 99% of my reads be for records that have nothing to do with `ids`.

Now, reading the specs, the raw QD32 IOPS of my SSD should allow me to collect all records in time (i.e., before the next request comes). But, what I observe with my trivial implementation is much much worse. I suspect that this is due to that being effectively a QD1 implementation:

- Read something from disk at a random location.
- Wait for the data to arrive, store it in RAM.
- Read the next thing from disk at another, independent location.

Now, the thing is I know all `ids` at the very beginning, and I would love it if there was a way to specify:

- As much in parallel as possible, read all the locations relevant to each element of `ids`.
- When that is done, carry on doing something on everything.

I am wondering if there is an easy way to get this done in Rust. I scouted for `file.parallel_read`-like functions in the standard library, for useful crates on crates.io, but to no avail. Which puzzles me because this should be a relatively common problem in a server / database setting. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sounds like memory mapped files

Comment: The idea being that I memmap the file, then..? Should I simply replace the "seek / read" loop with an "access various portions of the memory" loop? Won't this still make my implementation effectively QD1? Or will the compiler somehow understand that it can prefetch stuff for all next elements of `ids`?

Comment: If you have the file mmaped, you can then `madvise MADV_WILLNEED` (assuming that's Linux, other POSIX systems may have some equivalent) the bits that you want ahead of time. The kernel may or may not act on that advice.

Comment: I think your bottleneck won't be IOPS but instead latency and how you might be sitting around waiting for data more than actually doing anything useful. With threads or async you might be able to step around any blocking operations and do things with a better degree of concurrency, as in fan out into N tasks that each access the memory-mapped file. It'll take some testing and tuning but that should force the OS to queue up accesses and keep the process busy.

Comment: Honestly an `async` wrapper around memory mapped files would be your best solution, if there's a crate for such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the architecture you're targeting, there is the [`posix_fadvise`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html) syscall:

> Programs can use `posix_fadvise()` to announce an intention to access file data in a specific pattern in the future, thus allowing the kernel to perform appropriate optimizations.

You would pass the offset, `RECORD_SIZE`, and probably the `POSIX_FADV_WILLNEED` advise. Both the function and constant are available in the [libc](https://crates.io/crates/libc) crate. This same idea can be done with memory mapped files using `posix_madvise()` and `POSIX_MADV_WILLNEED` as hinted in the comments.

You then will need to do some performance tuning to determine how far ahead to make these calls. Not early enough and the data isn't there when you want it, and too early means you're needlessly adding pressure on your system memory.